# Flutter project from GitHub

Tags: github, flutter

This might be a simple question but I am not able to get around it. I have a Flutter project in my Windows 10 machine and checked in to my private repository in GitHub via Android Studio.

Now I want to create a same working environment on another Windows 10 or Mac. My question is, how can I checkout the project and work on it as it is missing the supported files like .metadat, project_name.iml etc?

Below image shows what I have in the github right now.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a git question than anything else. If you have files locally that you need to have exactly the same on another machine, you should check those in. If those files are in the `.gitignore` file in your project, that might be for a good reason, but if you really want to sync them, you should remove them from the `.gitignore` and, for each file, `git add -f [the file]`, then commit and push those files.